# Moderator pro tempore nomination

Tags: discussion, moderators

According to [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), three temp moderators will be selected in two weeks of beta.

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

I'm going to propose some persons to vote, and you can nominate yourself too or may propose someone.

Comment: What are the requirements to be a mod? It might be useful if you listed them in your question body... That's my opinion. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, Heh, I am not Stack Exchange, so I don't know the official answer. But I personally don't think there is such a requirements.

Comment: @Alenanno, this is how they did on English.SE site - http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/160/select-your-provisional-moderators

Answer (score 12):

Tsuyoshi Ito

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/15/tsuyoshi-ito

He is native Japanese Speaker, and fluent English speaker.

We might need native persons on this site, seriously!

He did great contribution to site meta as well

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/tsuyoshi-ito

Comment: If chosen, I am happy to accept.

Answer (score 11):

Amanda S

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/amanda-s

She also have great Japanese knowledge, Looks Native speaker of English

and contributed a lot even on meta as well

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/amanda-s

Comment: I accept the nomination.

Answer (score 9):

Self-nominations? OK... so here goes...

"I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself."

Like everybody else here, I do have a day job and a life that might force me to take a break from heavy moderating duties at times, but for the time being, I'll be happy to help out with what I can. :-)

Comment: Thank you for offering the first self-nomination!

Answer (score 8):

YOU

Has been a great contributing member with a ton of great answers that have been upped by the community. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/100/you

Most importantly, he has had a very large presence across the entire site, which would make him great as a moderator.

Comment: One thing I need to explain here is, I am neither Native on English nor Japanese.

Comment: As far as I am concerned your English is more than adequate to answer questions on this site. :D

Answer (score 7):

Derek Schaab

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/94/derek-schaab

Long time Japanese Language Enthusiast, Teacher Level explanations.

Contributed to the site by correcting English grammar to horrible posts like [mine](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/560/revisions) :D

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote my own nomination, since I've no experience moderating an online community and this is the first SE I've ever participated in. :)

Answer (score 7):

Boaz Yaniv

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/153/boaz-yaniv  ([meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/153/boaz-yaniv))

A linguistics student that always has very detailed answers, often providing a different perspective from all of the other answers.

Comment: I'm honored, but I don't think being a moderator is for me. I mostly write answers, and sometimes edit other people's posts for clarity. But moderators also have to know when to **delete**, and in places where I've been a moderator I've rarely ended up deleting things.

Comment: @Boaz, I personally think deletion is least important thing on SE. Even you don't delete anything, you could be good moderator. And also 2k users (10k users on non-beta site) can also vote to delete (3+ votes needed), so you don't need to worry about that, IMHO.

Comment: @YOU: Maybe I was under the wrong impression. I thought moderators are mainly there to delete and edit posts when no one else would and without a vote. Since I'm fine with just having delete votes (which I'll probably never use) and edit privileges, I wasn't sure what being a moderator is good for.

Comment: @Boaz Someone just linked a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) describing moderator duties.

Comment: Yep, I know that. I'm okay with doing all that stuff (most of it can be done by rep. too), but I'm just not a deleter. :)

Answer (score 3):

hippietrail

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/125/hippietrail

Looks like he has great experience with editorial stuff
  - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Hippietrail

And he actually did proposed some tag wiki edits and alikes

and have great contributions to site meta too

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/125/hippietrail

Comment: Thanks for the nomination, which I didn't expect with such rudimentary Japanese. I'll have to think about it though because over on Wiktionary I lost plenty of sleep over bureaucratic arguing and stuff though it does look like the nature of SE has neatly avoided a lot of that and I am keen to help give the site some from in its infancy.

Answer (score 3):

**[makdad](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/87/makdad)** ([meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87/makdad))

Active on both the main site and meta, has done some helpful retagging and commenting

Comment: Thanks Amanda!  I'd be happy to if asked!

Answer (score 3):

Let me express a small concern: there are no self-nominations so far.

I understand that not everyone is interested in doing a moderator.  I have not written any name because I do not want to cause any pressure.  (While being nominated is an honor, it is a burden at the same time.)  I just assumed that if someone was interested, he/she would nominate him/herself.

However, I noticed that there have been no self-nominations so far.  This may be making the self-nomination more difficult.

Please consider nominating yourself if you are willing to spend some time doing janitorial work.  Not everything about being a moderator will be fun, but I appreciate your work.  Thanks.

Comment: Good point.  I think because the poll was already seeded with several nominations, people got shy.  For what it's worth, I would have self-nominated if YOU hadn't beaten me to the punch.  The same might be true for others who have been nominated here.