# List of 7+ essential meta questions for the beta period

Tags: discussion

OK, so as the beta testers we're supposed to work on key aspects of the site's attributes.  Taking a cue from other betas, I've made this list so we can easily find them all.

---

■ This question is a community wiki so please edit it and change these list items into links when the questions are made. ■

---

(Some from the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), some from other betas)

**Site content**

- What counts as off topic/on topic - please tag using [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions)
- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-should-our-faq-contain) - please tag using [faq-topics](/questions/tagged/faq-topics)
- How should we tag questions about {subject}? - please tag using [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

**Community**

- [Moderators](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/moderator-pro-tempore-nomination)
- [Who is our target audience?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-our-target-audience)

**Promotion**

- Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline
- How should we promote this site?

**Look & feel**

- What should our [logo](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/new-logo-for-japanese-language-usage) and site design look like?
- 404 Image
- CAPTCHA Image

---

Thanks for helping out in the beta. [Let's vote often!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/lets-vote-often)

<sub>(Text nicked from [meta.askubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/81/site-attribute-questions-top-7), which in turn nicked from [meta.photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/site-attribute-questions-top-7)).</sub>

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to ask each question separately. Especially since we can click on them to vote whereas clicking on answers that cover multiple points are not clear votes on the individual points.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The question was meant to be a meta-list of things we should be sorting out during the beta. I'll change the question title and put a notice on the top to make it clear. > done

Comment: It was a very good question by the way!

Answer (score 3):

Great idea!

My 2 yen so far:

**Site content**

- on-topic/off-topic has already been quite extensively discussed. Even though there is still some ongoing debate about ["target audience"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-our-target-audience) or whether ["JLU should accept cultural questions"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/should-uniquely-cultural-questions-be-acceptable-in-jlu), I think most people agree with the original beta statement of purpose ("everybody welcome" and "only somewhat-language-related questions"). The rest is just fine-tuning.
- Current FAQ looks good. There's been a few questions pertaining to possible FAQ modifications. I will now go over them and make sure they are all tagged appropriately and we can quickly go over in one fell swoop at the end (**Update**: done).
- Question format has also been extensively discussed when the site was in pre-launch. Not sure we need any more examples, but...

**Promotion**

- Tagline: Not sure what else beside our current title and a one-line welcome message is needed. Based on other SE sites, something like "Welcome to Q&A for students, speakers and anybody with an interest in the Japanese Language" could do. The "students, speakers etc." part is the only unknown and depends a lot on the outcome of our "target audience" debate.
- Promotion: Like any other SE site, and like most things in general, 99% of promotion will be word-of-mouth through social networks and the internet. Beside encouraging people to do so, not sure what else there is (providing options and tools to do so, is definitely SE's job, not ours). Perhaps later on, we can organise to pick particularly good question/answers and spread them around ("Share-your-favourite-question Friday" or something), but that doesn't strike me as a priority.

**Look and Feel**

- Will be a hard one, I feel. From experience, everybody has an opinion on how things should look, not two people alike. Also: everybody is a critic, but few really want to spend the time it takes to make a logo/design etc.
- How about starting with the Logo, with a question dedicated to people posting their ideas (as in: *actual* graphics) and other people suggesting improvements/changes. Once we've narrowed it down a little (and assuming we even have the luxury of choice), we can organise a vote of sorts to pick the logo. **Update**: [over here!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/new-logo-for-japanese-language-usage)
- Once a logo is picked, it is rather easy to pick the rest (matching colour theme etc).

Anything else?