# What should the site colourscheme be?

Tags: discussion, beta

We've already [began discussing the new logo](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/new-logo-for-japanese-language-usage).

In that discussion some of the answers including my own blurred into the topics of overall theme and colourscheme but I think it's cleaner to separate each. We can certainly mention and link to related points between the questions.

I started another [topic about the overall theme / background / look](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-should-the-sites-theme-background-look-feel-include-and-not-include).

Answer (score 1):

This picture is already on the question about the logo but I might as well place my $.02 on colour. I think that the unbleached silk and pinkish bark colours appear calm and attractive, and still have a sort of Japanese tone to them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, I support light text on dark backgrounds. This is partially due to the fact that I get light-sensitive migraines and end up having to use CSS-hacking extensions like Stylish to ease the pain at the cost of covering up Stack interface widgets.

Answer (score -3):

**Red on white**

Vote this **up** if you are **in favour** of red on white playing a big part in the future colourscheme.

Vote this **down** if you are **against** red on white as a major part of the colourscheme.

Comment on this answer about why you feel either way.

Comment: Red on white seems like the color scheme outsiders associate with Japan.  The [traditional Japanese colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_colors_of_Japan) are much subtler and prettier.

Comment: @Amanda: Please add another answer mentioning more about those colours so people can vote on it the same way. I for one am a bit ignorant despite many trips to Japan.

Comment: I think instead of focussing on "what represents Japan" the colour scheme should make reading comfortable. I'm not in favour of glaring colours.

Comment: @Flaw: Of course we have to choose readable colours but there are obviously many readable colours so we have to choose from among them anyway. #FF0000 on #FFFFFF would certainly be a terrible choice (-: