# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks absolutely great.

That is all.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the icon of Japanese was changed together with other language sites. The Japanese Language site icon was "Jp". But I still prefer the "あ" of hiragana.

http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#culture

Can this be changed?
There was no consensus reached on the previous wiki on icon.
[New Logo for Japanese Language & Usage](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/new-logo-for-japanese-language-usage)

Comment: This site will get its its logo and design once it graduates.

Comment: ok. so your the one who designed the new layout? nice redesign. much lighter and less clutter.

Comment: yes I did, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when a question title has furigana on it, the badge page for badges that display question titles has some clipping issues:

[image: Question titles with furigana are cut in half]

Note also the last question has sawa's badge clipped (I did not crop that out).

Also, out of curiosity, why are some titles bigger than others?  Even the English-only ones like #3, #4, and #6 are different sizes.

Comment: It looks like the reason some titles are bigger than others is because the hyperlinks to questions (`.question-hyperlink`) have a `font-size` of 17 pixels, whereas the hyperlinks to answers (`.answer-hyperlink`) don't. The reason why they're clipped is because the class `.user-list` has overflow set to hidden (which I'm guessing was deliberate to stop content going outside it's container.)

Comment: i have put in a fix for this. it will be in the next production build.

Comment: @Jin Looks fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the favicon of the main site is still the old design. Is this intended?

[image]

Comment: you need to hard refresh the browser, it's most likely cached right now. or you can go to http://cdn.sstatic.net/japanese/img/favicon.ico and http://cdn.sstatic.net/japanesemeta/img/favicon.ico and hard refresh the favicons individually.

Comment: @Jin Thanks. I got it refreshed.