# New Site Design!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/japanese-language-new-site-design).

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackjapanese) and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with **design** and **bug**.

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your Chat theme!

Comment: Thanks! Looks great.

Answer (score 6):

Something is weird with the [SVG that contains the logo](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/japanese/img/sprites.svg). For me the logo looks like this:

[image: How I see the logo]

This happens on all zoom levels (Firefox 47) and when I open the SVG in Inkscape, I see the same, yet the effect disappears when I ungroup or move the logo.

Same thing happens on Meta.

Comment: See http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1587/9212

Comment: @GoBusto no, there is a circle, 
the problem 
I also see 
is missing "N", instead there is a weird slash.

Comment: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1585/9222