# Centre the あ inside the site logo

Tags: bug, design

I think the logo should be shifted slightly into the (1,1) direction (45 degrees), i.e. up and to the right. The bounding box may be centred perfectly, but the character inside the circle looks lopsided.

*Edit.*

It should be a bit more subtle than this, but the circle being 40x40 pixels (the あ being 22x22), a shift of one pixel up and one pixel to the right (or one pixel up) already looks better (to me):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about this... take a look: http://cl.ly/443L271w1n47

Comment: @Paweł I wonder if it'd be better when the あ go (x,y) = (0, -0.5).

Comment: I imagine Earthliŋ was using traditional coordinates where (1,1) is *up* and to the right, not inverted coordinates where (1,1) is *down* and to the right.

Comment: @snailplane Right, with (x,y) I meant x to the right and y up. (This is also what my vector graphics software uses.) I guess for HTML people use inverted coordinates, so that the origin is at the top left (rather than the bottom left)...?

Comment: What if you moved it up, but not to the right?

Comment: @snailplane Added this option. I feel it should be somewhere between these two (maybe closer to the one you suggested).

Comment: Ooh, like up 0.75 pixels, right 0.25 pixels maybe?

Comment: Good & detailed question; typically, it is correct for characters to be centered correctly

Answer (score 5):

The left logo is how I think it should look, the right one is the current one (with centred bounding boxes). Small & large

[image]
[image]

Relative to the old one (blue)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I personally have a feeling that the あ should go up a bit.

And when we're at it, I'd like to mention the font of あ too.

[image]

It seems that letter shape of the current design (on left) is a simple modification of that on earlier draft (on right), but the bottom part becomes a little cramped because of the protrusion.

I'd like to vote for replacing the font as in [the original advice by HiruneDiver](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1579/7810), so that it'd look more in. (I personally prefer 源ノ角ゴシック and 源柔ゴシック, but it doesn't matter.) If you're concerned about legibility, you could just keep the favicon size icon as the status quo (it's already different from bigger icon, isn't it?), because the problem is unnoticeable in smaller size.