# Where's the blue colour?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

In the site design release post [Japanese Language New Site Design](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1564/542), this colour scheme was shown:

[image]

I imagined that one colour would be for the main site, and one for the meta site, since for other SE sites the **main site is coloured differently from its meta**. (I think the main site's colour is also related to the Chat site?)

But it seems main, meta (and Chat) are all grey for our site.

Is this (both sites (and Chat) being grey) intentional?
Where can I see the blue background? Is there a display options tab somewhere?

Comment: At the moment the main site is "indigo on off-white with red accents", the meta site is "dark grey on off-white with no accents". Considering that on the main page we have "off-black on white" in the list of questions, a dark background would look more like http://gaming.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What's indigo on the main site? I suppose red accent refers to the redness of the Ask Question button.

Comment: Try hovering your mouse cursor over a tag or link for the 'red accent'

Comment: Here's the colour palette as outlined [in the original design post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/1564/2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIBNC.png ... Where's the green? Grey? Bluish-grey? Dark blue?

Comment: The dark blue / indigo is in the logo (text colour of `JAPANESE LANGUAGE`) and used for question titles. The green is used for `2 answers` under the votes on the main page.