# Why are the Up and Down Vote arrows a 初心者マーク?

Tags: discussion

So the up and downvote arrows look like a  初心者マーク. Was this on purpose?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They were supposedly inspired by 矢絣 but with only one monochromatic arrow it can easily look like a monochrome 初心者マーク.

More information [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/japanese-language-new-site-design).