# What is the badge icon of Japanese Language Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, badges

[image: badge]
When I looked the [badge](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/badges) icon of Japanese Language Stack Exchange, 
the first image came to my mind is the Ancient Chinese Coins.

[image: coin]

What's it actually?

So maybe change it to other more representative & relative icon is better.

For example, the petal of cherry blossom flower (single piece).

Comment: Where did you see this? All I can see is あ enclosed in a circle.

Comment: @droooze I am saying the badge icon. it looks like Chinese old coin. The image is from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Chinese_coinage). It's hard to relate the Japanese Language.

Comment: what is the "badge icon" and where can one see it? A screenshot could be helpful here.

Comment: Hmm..most of the other SE sites use a filled circle. This icon isn't totally irrelevant, though - Japan also used coins like this in the past; see [匁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%81).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's supposed to be based on the Japanese *mon* coin.  From [Wikimedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_mon_(currency)):

[image: coins from Wikimedia]

Confirmed by Pawel in [this comment thread](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/japanese-language-new-site-design#comment3745_1565):

> @G-Cam is right - this is inspired by the "mon" coin. Chose it because it has a unique shape and can be viewed at small sizes. – Paweł May 24 '16 at 13:37

I don't know anything about Chinese or Japanese coins, so I don't know how uniquely Japanese these coins were or weren't.

However, I believe custom badges are one of the fun parts of the site that [SE's designers want to get rid of in order to make all sites look the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), so I'm not sure if any proposed changes will be actively considered.

Comment: It's uniquely *East Asian*, but not uniquely Japanese. China has been minting [coins like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_Liang#/media/File:S-88_or_82,_W_Han_banliang,_Empress_Gao,_187-180,_34mm.jpg) since ~200 BCE, and China, [Ryukyus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryukyuan_mon), [Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_cash), and [Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_mun) have been universally this kind of coin as currency before the turn of the 20th century.